# Adding text boxes dynamically in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I have a requirement, where I need to provide adding text boxes dynamically. Consider following example:

TextBox1 TextBox2 TextBox3 AddButton

First, I need to  display text boxes as above and one add button next to them. When clicking on the add button, there should appear a new line of textboxes as above. How can this be implemented in GWT ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all let's create UI file for your task:

```
<g:VerticalPanel>
    <g:FlowPanel ui:field="textAreaContainer">
        <g:TextBox ui:field="Textbox1"/>
        <g:TextBox ui:field="Textbox2"/>
        <g:TextBox ui:field="Textbox3"/>
    </g:FlowPanel>
    <g:Button ui:field="addTButton" />
</g:VerticalPanel>
```

There is no any styles and etc.. only as example.
And lest create java file for this view.

```
public class SampleGWT {
interface SampleGWTUiBinder extends UiBinder<VerticalPanel, SampleGWT> {
}

private static SampleGWTUiBinder ourUiBinder = GWT.create(SampleGWTUiBinder.class);
@UiField
FlowPanel textAreaContainer;
@UiField
TextBox Textbox1;
@UiField
TextBox Textbox2;
@UiField
TextBox Textbox3;
@UiField
Button addTButton;

public SampleGWT() {
    VerticalPanel rootElement = ourUiBinder.createAndBindUi(this);
}

@UiHandler("addTButton")
public void onAddTB(ClickEvent event){
    TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
    textAreaContainer.add(textBox);
}}
```

If you have any question - please welcome.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. after adding few rows, on click of addButton i need to know which row's button is clicked. please help me how to achieve this?Thanks!

Comment: This code should helps you:for (int i=0;i<textAreaContainer.getWidgetCount();i++){
           TextBox textItem = (TextBox)textAreaContainer.getWidget(i);
           textItem.
        }

Comment: You need to insert this code to your onClick method. getWidget function return your row which you could cast to anything that  required for your logic.